# What is the best way to handle JSON with unquoted keys?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I use a 3rd service for my website, it returns data in a simple JSON string and the problem is JSON key names are not enclosed in quotes.

For example, both `ServiceStack.Text.JsonObject.Parse` and `System.Json.JsonObject.Parse` failed to get correct JSON object:

```
{ firstName: "Tien", lastName: "Do", title: "Developer" }
```

But `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode` did well, and of course Chrome/FF can also display above JSON string correctly.

Is quoted key name always required? Is there other way to parse this string with ServiceStack.Text?

Comment: Can you contact the 3rd party and ask them to stop lying in their specs and send actual JSON?

Comment: I can't, it's a public service.

Comment: Public services are also run by people.  You may be able to contact them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://jsonlint.com/ the keys must be quoted.

Of course you can always use javascript JSON library to generate correct JSON from the JS object you get from server. JSON.stringify(myObject) will produce correct JSON string.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using JavaScript in this case.

Comment: Sure, I am sure there is an equivalent in your language. I have not used c# for this but json.org lists a bunch of libs. here is one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/

Comment: Sure, I just note that I was asking for another/better "C# solution" (if there is any). System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode can handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

yeah

you should use `"` always

like this :

```
{
    "firstName": "Tien",
    "lastName": "Do"
}
```

try to verify with http://jsonlint.com/